# How to hide tab and white spaces in sublime text 3 for specific file type

Tags: python-3.x, sublimetext3

I can't make the tabs and white space disappear. I've tried to set `"draw_white_space": "selection",` and `"draw_white_space": "none",` in preference > user, but none of those worked. See in image below how it looks:

[Python script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UG7bn.png)

Before I save a file as python script (.py) tabs and white spaces didn't show, but they appear immediately after saving the file with .py.

[before saving as .py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kwa1d.png)

Can someone help me set sublime to NOT show tabs and white spaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds you like this setting has been overridden for `.py` files. Do this:

1. Open any `.py`.
2. Preferences > Settings - More > Syntax Specific - User
3. Set `"draw_white_space": "none"` (or `"selection"`, whatever you prefer).

In Sublime Text, each syntax can override these settings.

Comment: Yup! Worked! Thanks!